# Using 'LENGTHOF' in dosbox's masm

Tags: assembly, masm

I am running masm within dosbox environment.
Using the masm.exe from the following link

https://medium.com/@axayjha/getting-started-with-masm-8086-assembly-c625478265d8

I am trying to read the length of an array by using 'LENGTHOF'.
When i trying to assemble the codes, the following is shown up.

Please check the following snapshot of the assembling output.

[image]

The following are my codes to run

```
  .386
  .model small
  .stack 100
  .data
        ; Your data definition
        message1 db "Please key in numbers: ", "$"
        message2 db "The number you keyed in is: ", "$"
        nextLine db 0Ah, 0Dh, "$"
   .code
main proc
        ; Your program here
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov dx,LENGTHOF nextLine

    
END_PROGRAM:
   mov ah, 4ch ; Program ending
   int 21h
   end main
```

Is there any steps needed to enable the functions of LENGTHOF ?

Comment: `LENGTHOF` requires at least MASM 6.1 AFAIK. You could try `LENGTH` and see if that works.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for commenting. Yes, the working keyword is `LENGTH`. But what I encounter is `LENGTH` always returns 1 no matter which variable I put in.

Answer (score 1):

LENGTHOF was introduced in MASM Version 6.0
I've used this site [MASM32 SDK Version 11 Downloads](https://www.masm32.com/download.htm) to update MASM.

[image: masmv6]